# How do you assign any role to a user in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js, roles

I don't want a command that whenever you do -role, it already has only one in place to give to a user. I would like one that whatever you put a role as the second argument, it gives that user that role (unless of course that role doesn't exist). So if you do -role @user Blue, it gives them the 'Blue' role, if you do -role @user Red, it gives them the 'Red' role.

I guess best similarity to this would be the Dyno bot, whatever role you put as the second argument, it gives that role to the user.

Comment: Please view the documentation and do some research first. You are expected to attempt this before asking for debugging help

Comment: Hi, please supply some sample code that make it easier to discuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

I suppose you use the command handler from the [discordjs guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files), so the `args` array is the array of words (arguments) after the command itself.

```js
//search the role based on the name that the user provided:
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === args[1]);
//if the role doesn't exist, create it
if (!role) {
  role = await message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: args[1] } });
}
//get the mentioned user
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
//add the role to the user
member.roles.add(role);
```